# schedule two local notifications one hour apart in ionic mobile app

Tags: ionic3, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I have to schedule two local notifications in my ionic 3 mobile app. These notifications need to be 1 hour apart from each other. For example: if first notification is sent out at 3:00 pm then the second local notification should be sent out at 4:00 pm.

Can someone suggest a way of getting the time at which first notification was triggered so that I can add 1 hour to it and schedule the second notification.

Thanks in advance.
SKR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the local notifications plugin here:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/

use the schedule method like so:

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({
  id: 1,
  text: 'Single Immediate ILocalNotification',
  sound: isAndroid? 'file://sound.mp3': 'file://beep.caf',
  data: { secret:'hi' }
});

let originalTime = new Date().getTime();

// Schedule delayed notification (1 hour from original time)
this.localNotifications.schedule({
   id: 2,
   text: 'Delayed 1 hour ILocalNotification',
   at: new Date(originalTime + 3600000), // 3600000 is 1 hour in milliseconds
   sound: isAndroid? 'file://sound.mp3': 'file://beep.caf',
   data: { secret:'hi 1 hour later' }
});
```